# Excel formula to extract a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Could someone please give me the excel formula to extract the string between the user tags:

```
  <user>secAuthority=default</user>
```

I need the string **secAuthority=default** as output

Comment: something like `=MID(A1,FIND(">",A1)+1,FIND("</",A1)-FIND(">",A1)-1)`?

Comment: this works . thanks Dirk

=MID(A1,FIND(">",A1)+1,FIND("</",A1)-FIND(">",A1)-1)

Answer (score 0):

you can mix the FIND, RIGHT, and LEFT functions to make a substring function - knowing that you want what comes after the first ">" up to the second "<"

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute it out

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"</user>",""),"<user>","")
```

Or, being we know `<user>` is 6 chars long and `</user>` is 7 we could do

```
=MID(A1,7,LEN(A1)-13)
```

And finally, just playing around to make it work regardless of what is in the triangular brackets.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"</",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),">",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1),LEN(A1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

And let's not forget Flash Fill, available in XL 2013 and up. Type the first value. Type the second value. In some cases you may need to type a third value, but then Excel will come up with a suggestion in light grey. You can make corrections and it will apply the new rules.

This is perfect for one-offs where you don't want to spend two hours to automate a job that would take a minute manually.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Just to put my comment in an answer:

> something like `=MID(A1,FIND(">",A1)+1,FIND("</",A1)-FIND(">",A1)-1)`

Works for all strings like `<***>Some Text</***>`.